# API connect to mysql sometimes not performing queries

Tags: php, mysql, api, fsockopen

a very puzzling and exhausting problem of mine:

I developed an API to allow others to draw information from my database. My server collects the POSTed info, writes up a mysql query, performs the query [$query = mysql_query($string, $connection);] , and returns the results (very simple).

the problem is that sometimes (say 1 out of every 5 tries) no info is returned. My server logs  say that the resource ($query) is boolean (and therefore no results). My server receives the info from the remote users of the API every single time, the problem seems to be that my queries are sometimes just not being performed...

Why is this happening?

Is it a mysql performance issue? I never seem to have even a hint of a performance issue for queries made on my own page (i.e. not from the API)!

please help...

Comment: Have you done anything to try debugging, such as logging the post values, query string that you're building, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query might be failing. Try doing this:

```
mysql_query($string, $conn)or die(mysql_error());
```

If the query is generating an exception/error, it will stop the script and display the MySQL error. Using that error, you can fix your query so that everything will work fine eventually.

By the way, you are using $string, but it might be a better idea to use $builtQuery, because "string" might be confusing if you are going to need to edit the script later on.

Greetings.

Comment: thank God! sometimes the most obvious solution is the most overlooked! I tried every other test, but not this "or die(mysql_error())" test. The problem was there was no mysql_select_db(---,---). sometimes it performed the query and sometimes it did not. thank you

Comment: No problem. Actually, mysql_error() almost always can fix any MySQL-related problems. It gives you a good explanation of what is going on. And if it doesn't output anything, you know it's not MySQL failing. Always handy :-)